# $_POST data to a new message

Tags: php, ios

The idea is to instantly send a push notification to a user whenever someone looks at their photo.

This is the function that selects the photo data to help show the photo when it's pressed by a user.

```
result = query("SELECT p.IdPhoto, p.device_token, p.IdUser FROM photos p JOIN login l ON (l.IdUser = p.IdUser) WHERE p.IdPhoto='%d'", $IdPhoto) ;
```

And this is part the function that selects the message data when the photo is pressed by someone.

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT device_token FROM active_users WHERE secret_code = ? AND device_token <> ? AND device_token <> '0'");
```

Both php functions are in different files on my computer when the app is at runtime.

The second message sends a message to all active users in the database. Is there a way to pass the device_token from the first method so that it is the only receiver of the message in the device_token field in the second method? I have been playing around with global variables for a few months but I find it a lot different when using posted data over and http server and using that with a variable in the message file .

The good news is , what ever the final method is, the database has fields that connected the tapped photo to that users `IdPhoto` , `device_token` , and `IdPhoto` so either field can be Posted to the server and passed to the new message to check for the concurrent `device_token` field.

[image]

Question: can I use the device token from the first message for the device token value in the second message in real time?

Comment: A bit more clearly, device_token is sent from Apple Push Notification Server and the device_token can be change. Your mobile application needs to sent the device_token back to your server for recording or updating user's device_token. In your case, you need to do a mapping between user's id and device_tokens in DB. For your question, you may use same device_token to push different message twice, but the tokens must be updated. Remind: 1 user has multiple devices.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I should have thought of that much sooner. 2 messages is the way to go. Thanks!